# When I force downloading a file from a page, it split te file name by SPACE /C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-headers, force-download

Here is my code for the Force Download:

```
        // URL = Download.aspx?Url=How to use the Application.txt    

        string q = Request.QueryString["Url"].ToString();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "Attachment; Filename=" + file);
        Response.ContentType = "Text/Plain";
        Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("Directory/" + q));
        Response.End();
```

The Dialog Box that apears in Firefox says: You are going to open the file:
And the filename is displayed just ass How (the name should be: How to use the Application.txt ). The sama I mentioned if I try to wright the filename for my self:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "Attachment; Filename=How to use the Application.txt");
```

The same apears. Please Help!

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6745788/30594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mime files names should be double quoted.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", 
                   "Attachment; Filename=\"" + file + "\"");
```

This can be found in [RFC 2616(HTTP 1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"

Revised in [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) to allow file names without quotes too if they didn't contain disallowed charecters like spaces.

> Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=example.html

Answer (score 2):

You should put double quotes around the filename. Here is how to do that:

```
    string q = Request.QueryString["Url"].ToString();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
        + file + "\"");
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(d + q));
    Response.End();
```

Note that I also changed your Strings upper/lower case to now "Content-Disposition", "attachment", "filename", "text/plain". You should use them in that way to not get into trouble with browsers that handle that quite strict.

If that doesn't work correctly, try:

```
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;
        Filename=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file) + "\"");
```

Then the spaces in filenames are URL encoded.

Comment: +1, had the exact same problem yesterday - where were you? ;)

Comment: Either at work or asleep; In case you know how to enable that nifty "Omnipresence"-feature for real life... just let me know. I would give you a bounty of 300, thought ;-)

Comment: According to Microsoft, it SHOULD be ready in .NET 7.5 - this.Omnipresence.Enabled = true;

Comment: Is there an OpenSource alternative? I actually don't want a Microsoft product being omnipresent together with me ;-)

Comment: Probably, if the Mono team get it together :P