# Download text as file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to download some text output from the screen as a text file. Following is the code. It's working on some pages and not working at all on other pages. Can anyone please suggest what's wrong here?

```
protected void Button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=output.txt");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string output = "Output";
    sb.Append(output);
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Could you solve someones problem if he would tell you that _"it's working on some pages and not working at all on other pages"_ without telling you what's not working?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As already mentioned by Joshua, you need to write the text to the output stream (using `Response` object). Also, don’t forget to invoke `Response.End()` after that.

```
protected void Button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string output = "Output";
    sb.Append(output);
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    
    string text = sb.ToString();
    
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", text.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"output.txt\"");

    Response.Write(text);
    Response.End();
}
```

Edit 1: added more details

Edit 2: I was reading other SO posts where users were recommending to put quotes around the filename:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"output.txt\"");
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001019/558486

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's still not working with the above code. The file download dialog is not being invoked.

Comment: I would consider writing the data as binary as well.

Comment: @RuiJarimba The button is in an UpdatePanel, when I removed the updatepanel, it worked.

Comment: this code works when used with `<a href= ""/>` but doesn't work with Button.
Actually I am sending parameters with a URL so I have to use http get or post with button. Any idea?

Comment: It's Write don't forget to use Response.End();

Comment: if it doesn't work, you might need to handle your ScriptManager: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11221536/375422

Answer (score 4):

If that's your actual code, you never write the text to the response stream, so the browser never receives any data.

At the very least, you should need

```
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

to write your text data to the response. Also, as an added bonus, if you know the length beforehand you should provide it using the `Content-Length` header so the browser can show the download progress.

You're also setting `Response.Buffer = true;` as part of your method but never explicitly flush the response to send it to the browser. Try adding a `Response.Flush()` after your write statement.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that line in the code above. It's still not working. Thanks.

Comment: @Vj87 See my update, you're buffering so it might not be sending the content to the browser when you expect. Also, if this is a large amount of text, the entire file won't get sent to the browser until the server has buffered everything. You can also try setting `Response.Buffer` to false.