# Create a text file and allow user to download in a lightswitch application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I would like to create a simple text file in my application and allow a user to download it. I have a web application built using `lightswitch`. I have already google and the responses doesn't help me as it relates to lightswitch.

[Download text as file in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755339/download-text-as-file-in-asp-net)

Here, the proposal is to use Response. However, that particular namespace isn't available to me in lightswitch. I tried using webclient and i got access denied. My code is below.

```
    using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient()) {

        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString() + "\\" + Application.Current.User.FullName + ".txt";
        string text = "A class is the most powerful data type in C#. Like a structure, " + "a class defines the data and behavior of the data type. ";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text);

        wc.DownloadFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString(), Application.Current.User.FullName + ".txt");

    }
```

I am able to write my text file to `APP_DATA`. However, when i tried using `webclient` to download it, it gives me access denied. Help me please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I upload and download Word files in my web application. I followed two articles to help me make this possible:

[How Do I: Import and Store a Data File](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmattsampson/archive/2011/05/23/how-to-import-and-store-a-data-file.aspx) (this one only discusses uploads but the process is similar)
[Upload and download file in Lightswitch 2011](http://gyansangrah.com/ArticleContent.aspx?ID=upload_and_download_file_in_lightswitch_2011)

In my solution, both upload and download follow the pattern in the first article for symmetry's sake. I didn't really care for the way the second article handled the download side. I can't remember exactly if the references mentioned in the second article are necessary for the way I did things. I have those references in my project but I know I use them for other things. And in VS2013 at least, the unloading and reloading of the project was not necessary.

Essentially, you need to create a custom Silverlight control to add this functionality. So add an `.xaml` file to your User Code. Both articles have examples of what should be in there and mine looks like this:

```xml
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="LightSwitchApplication.DownloadFileWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
           Width="380" Height="125" 
           Title="Select Where to Save File" >
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="75" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,15,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" Click="OKButton_Click" Width="75" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,15,80,0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button Content="Browse" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,10,0,0" Name="BrowseButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BrowseButton_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="FileTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" IsEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
</controls:ChildWindow>
```

VS2013 (which I'm using) and LightSwitch 2011 (which is what the articles are written for) handle the code behind the `.xaml` differently. I'm not sure how VS2012 handles it so you'll need to figure that part out. But in the code behind your custom Silverlight control, you need a constructor, functions that set `this.DialogResult` to `true` and `false` for the OK and Cancel buttons, respectively, and three properties:

1. a `DocumentStream` as a `MemoryStream` type to write the file to your computer
2. a `SaveFileStream` as a `FileStream` type to pull the file from the database
3. a `FileName` as a `String` type

The real work of saving the file takes place in the code for the Browse button.

```
private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Word Files (*.docx)|*.docx|(*.docm)|*.docm";
    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "docx";
    if ((saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)) {
        // Get File name, store and display to user
        this.FileTextBox.Text = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        this.m_FileName = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        this.FileTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
        try {
            // Open and store the File Stream
            this.DocumentStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // Inform the user of the problem
            MessageBox.Show("The file you are trying to save to is open in another applicaion." + "\r\n" + "Please close it and try again.", "File Already Open", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the `Filter` and `DefaultExt` set to handle Word docs but you can modify this to handle `.txt` or whatever you want. I've also added a bit more error handling than the examples in the articles based on my experiences using it.

Finally, in your screen code, you need invoke the custom control on the `Main` dispatcher and write the file to the database when the custom control closes.

```
partial void DownloadFile_Execute()
{
    // To invoke our own dialog, we have to do this inside of the "Main" Dispatcher
    // And, since this is a web application, we can't directly invoke the Silverlight OpenFileDialog
    // class, we have to first invoke our own Silverlight custom control (i.e. DownloadFileWindow)
    // and that control will be able to invoke the OpenFileDialog class (via the Browse button)
    Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        DownloadFileWindow downloadFileWindow = new DownloadFileWindow();
        downloadFileWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(downloadFileWindow_Closed);
        downloadFileWindow.Show();
    });
}

void downloadFileWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Invoked when our custom Silverlight window closes
    DownloadFileWindow downloadFile = (DownloadFileWindow)sender;

    try {
        // Continue if they hit the OK button AND they selected a file
        if ((downloadFile.DialogResult == true)) {
            // Write the document data stream from the database to the selected file
            using (Stream saveStream = new Stream(downloadFile.DocumentStream))
            {
                downloadFile.DocumentStream.WriteTo(saveStream);
            }
        }

        // Close and release the streams
        downloadFile.DocumentStream.Close();
        downloadFile.DocumentStream.Dispose();
        downloadFile.SaveFileStream.Close();
        downloadFile.SaveFileStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        string res = "One or more save location errors have occured:" + "\r\n";

        // Check to see if there is a Document Stream
        if ((downloadFile.DocumentStream == null)) {
            res = res + '\t' + "Document Stream is empty" + "\r\n";
        }
        // Check to see if there is a Save File Stream
        if ((downloadFile.SaveFileStream == null)) {
            res = res + '\t' + "Save File Stream is empty" + "\r\n";
        }
        // Check to see if there is a Safe File Name
        if ((downloadFile.SafeFileName == null)) {
            res = res + '\t' + "Safe File Name is empty" + "\r\n";
        }

        res = res + "\r\n" + "Please use the Browse button to select a location to save to. Specify a file name and then click Save.";

        this.ShowMessageBox(res, "Save Location Error", MessageBoxOption.Ok);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've added a lot more error handling to these functions as well, based on experience. Hopefully between the two articles and my examples you can create the functionality that you want.

*Note: I converted the code from VB.NET which is what my project is written in. So there may be errors that you have to correct for to make the syntax correct for C#.*